# 404 Not Found error while creating repositories through Github API?

Tags: git, curl, github, github-api

I am trying to use github api to create repositories under a particular organization. I was looking at this [site](https://developer.github.com/guides/getting-started/#create-a-repository) which talks about how to create repositories under a particular organization.

My github instance url is like this - `https://github.host.com`

And I want my repository to be like this after getting created -

```
https://github.host.com/david/ClientService
```

So I am executing below curl url and everytime I am getting `404 Not Found` -

```
curl -i -u david -d '{ "name": "CustomerRepo", "auto_init": true, "private": true, "gitignore_template": "nanoc" }' https://github.host.com/api/v3/user/david/repos
```

Below is the result I am getting -

```
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Server: GitHub.com
Date: Sat, 07 Feb 2015 20:43:32 GMT
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 102
Status: 404 Not Found
X-GitHub-Media-Type: github.v3
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
X-Frame-Options: deny
Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'none'
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: ETag, Link, X-GitHub-OTP, X-RateLimit-Limit, X-RateLimit-Remaining, X-RateLimit-Reset, X-OAuth-Scopes, X-Accepted-OAuth-Scopes, X-Poll-Interval
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
X-GitHub-Request-Id: fv4af52e-617c-4ga1-br2f-5cb51b1df3bb
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubdomains; preload
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff

{
  "message": "Not Found",
  "documentation_url": "https://developer.github.com/enterprise/2.0/v3"
}
```

Is there anything wrong I am doing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `/david` segment from your target URL.

The API [determines the user under which to create the repository based on authentication](https://developer.github.com/enterprise/2.0/v3/repos/#create):

> Create a new repository for the authenticated user.
>
> ```
> POST /user/repos
> ```